# ReactJS onClick function is not triggering correctly

Tags: javascript, reactjs, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

Function is ONLY triggering correctly if I add e.preventDefault(). However, I want it to push the user to '/' after the user submits the form. Here is the function I am trying to trigger:

```
onAddPoints = (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    //history.push('/');
    let { phoneNumber, points, onPointsChange } = this.state;

    //convert string to int -> calculate update points
    let p1 = Number(points);
    let p2 = Number(onPointsChange);
    const updatedPoints = p1 + p2; 

    //update points
    firebase.auth().onAuthStateChanged((user) => {
        if(user) {
            const docRef = database.collection('users').doc(user.uid).collection('customers').doc(phoneNumber);
            docRef.update({
                "points": updatedPoints
            }).then(() => {
                console.log('success');
            }).catch((error) => {
                console.log(error);
            })
        } else {
            window.location.href = '/';
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: Add `history.push('/')` in the same place you are calling `console.log('success')`

Answer (score 0):

You need to wait to see the result of your request.

If the request is right then is ok if you send the user to another page but if the request gets an error then you have to tell the user that something is wrong.

```
firebase.auth().onAuthStateChanged((user) => {
    if(user) {
        const docRef = database.collection('users').doc(user.uid).collection('customers').doc(phoneNumber);
        docRef.update({
            "points": updatedPoints
        }).then(() => {
            history.push('/');
            console.log('success');
        }).catch((error) => {
            console.log(error);
        })
    } else {
        window.location.href = '/';
    }
});
```

And is ok if you use `e.preventDefeault()` because it stops the default form action flow onSubmit which is go to the page that is setup in the `action='./update.php'` property. That's commonly used in php apps for example by doing that you send all the inputs info to that **update.php**.

Comment: Hi Arnold, thanks for the reply. But I tried this before. Without adding e.preventDefault() at the top the form will redirect me to '/' and throws no error. However, the update function does NOT actually update my data.

Comment: That's because it's not an error per se. We do that in order to achieve the existing code in `onSubmit` function.